# How to open flutter plugins at Xcode?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I want make some changes in plugin. For android part everything is clear. But how can I open iOs part of plugin? There are no Xcode project just several .h and .m files.

How to open iOs plugin at Xcode?

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player/video_player/ios

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First, be sure to run the example app at least once.

```
$ cd example
$ flutter run
```

Then open the project in Xcode. The Xcode project is in `example/ios`. The swift (or obj-c) code that implements the iOS end of the method channel is found in (replace the italic strings with the actual plugin name):

> Pods/Development
>   Pods/*plugin_name*/../../example/ios/.symlinks/plugins/*plugin_name*/ios/Classes

which you can find by opening the tree in the left pane.

Comment: I cannot believe that this isn't in the official documentation. Do people really write iOS plugins without intellisense?

Comment: Usually, yes, as most people use Xcode, which does not have IntelliSense, which is Microsoft technology.

Answer (score 8):

```
go to root of package then.
cd example
flutter build ios --no-codesign
Launch Xcode.
Select File > Open, and select the hello/example/ios/Runner.xcworkspace file.
```

The iOS platform code for your plugin is located in Pods/Development Pods/hello/../../example/ios/.symlinks/plugins/hello/ios/Classes in the Project Navigator.

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way to open Xcode is `xed ios` when you are in the root project directory.

The plugins are put in `$project_dir/ios/Pods`

The plugins are actually installed by running `pod install`. `flutter run` will call `pod install` for you while also building the app. If you want to save time, just run `cd ios; pod install` and don't build your app.